# Trouble understanding why a new temporary TreeNode has to be created when trying to invert a binary tree

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

```
public class Solution {
        public TreeNode invertTree(TreeNode root) {
        if(root == null) return null;
            TreeNode tmp = root.left;
            root.left = invertTree(root.right);
            root.right = invertTree(tmp);
            return root;
        }
}
```

I do not understand why the above solution works but the below solution does not.

```
public class Solution {
        public TreeNode invertTree(TreeNode root) {
        if(root == null) return null;
            root.left = invertTree(root.right);
            root.right = invertTree(root.left);
            return root;
        }
}
```

Will someone please elaborate on why there has to a temporary TreeNode in order for the program to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the first snippet doesn't create a new `TreeNode`. It just stores a reference to the original left child of the root.

If you don't keep that reference (as in the second snippet), you are losing the reference to the original left sub-tree of the root, since you assign to root.left the result of inverting the right sub-tree (in `root.left = invertTree(root.right);`), so `invertTree(root.left)` doesn't operate on the original left sub-tree of the root.

Another way to look at it - the reason for the temp variable is similar to the reason why a temporary variable is required in order to swap two variables.

Answer (score 0):

After the second assignment you assign root.right to root.left but the previous line sets root.left to be root.right and therefore your root.right equals itself.